# Add/show widget after some time in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a word: `money`. I want to show every letter from that word after 2 seconds delay: First show letter `m`, after 2 seconds on screen should be visible: `m-o`, after next two seconds: `m-o-n` etc. I am thinking about save every letter to array: [m-, o-,n-,e-,y] and after that using Timer add Text.
Things which I don't know how achieve: how can I split this word to this array? And How add/show Text using Timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's follow your approach and make it happen.
To make an array from word, use `split("")` and it will return a list of string.

Like this
`List<String> _totalChar = "money".split("");`

**Result**

[image: output]

**Full Widget**

If you want to play it on start, put `_textAnimationSetUp()` inside `initState()`. BTW, I'm not focusing on button state. Let me know if you face any trouble with this widget.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AnimatedText extends StatefulWidget {
  AnimatedText({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AnimatedTextState createState() => _AnimatedTextState();
}

class _AnimatedTextState extends State<AnimatedText> {
  Timer? timer;
  String buttonText = "play";

  ///* let's make list from word
  List<String> _totalChar = "money".split("");
  List<String> _visibleChar = [];

  int currentIndex = 0;

  _textAnimationSetUp() async {
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        if (currentIndex < _totalChar.length)
          _visibleChar.add(
              "${currentIndex > 0 ? "-" : ""}${_totalChar[currentIndex++]}");
        else
          timer.cancel();
      });
    });
  }

  get _textStyle => TextStyle(
        fontSize: 40,
      );

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (timer != null && timer!.isActive) timer!.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _play() async {
    setState(() {
      currentIndex = 0;
      _visibleChar.clear();
      buttonText = "restart";
    });
    if (timer != null && timer!.isActive) timer!.cancel();
    _textAnimationSetUp();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              //* removing everything except  letter and -
              _visibleChar
                  .toString()
                  .replaceAll(" ", "")
                  .replaceAll(",", '')
                  .replaceAll("[", '')
                  .replaceAll("]", ""),
              style: _textStyle,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _play();
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: Text(buttonText),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Future` delay for every letter. Something like this:

```
timer() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 200));
    setState(() {
        letterVisible = true;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install :

dependencies:
animated_text: ^1.0.2

Then :

```
import 'package:animated_text/animated_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool play = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Animated Text'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: 300,
              child: AnimatedText(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                speed: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                controller: AnimatedTextController.loop,
                displayTime: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                wordList: ['animations.', 'are.', 'easier.', 'now.'],
                textStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 55,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```